# Implementing a Base Interface Problems

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following interfaces defined in a base library project:

```
public interface IWorkContext {
    T User<T>() where T : IUser;

    // Note this method is kind of a shortcut so i don't
    // have to keep passing in T
    IUser User();
}

public interface IUser {
    int Id { get; }
    string UserName { get; }
}
```

Now I have another project which references the one above with the following class (which implements IUser).

```
public class User : IUser {
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
   // ... Code removed for brevity
}
```

Now i also need to implement IWorkContext. Here's my first attempt:

```
public class DefaultWorkContext : IWorkContext {
    private readonly IUsersService _usersService;

    public DefaultWorkContext(IUsersService usersService) {
        _usersService = usersService;
    }

    public T User<T>() where T : IUser {
        return _usersService.GetUser<T>(1));
    }

    public User User() {
        return User<User>();
    }
}
```

However this gives the error:

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
>   or method '...GetUser(int)'. There is no boxing conversion or type
>   parameter conversion from 'T' to 'User'.

I'm sure there's something fundamental i'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate any advice on this model can be improved. Thanks

**Edit** (as requested here's the GetUser method):

```
public T GetUser<T>(int id) where T : User {
    return _session.Get<T>(id);
}
```

Note: _session is an NHibernate session.

Comment: Can we have the code for your UserService and the GetUser<T> method please?

Comment: Also, what kind of generic type does GetUser accept? I suspect the error comes from here.

Comment: We need to see IUserService...

Comment: I've updated the question with the GetUser method.

Comment: what is `IUserService` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing a generic type as a type parameter to your `GetUser()` method, that **may** not satisfy the condition of inheritance of the generic type accepted by your `GetUser()` method.

The compiler ensures that the type passing as parameters always satisfy the type conditions.
Indeed, you could write a `class NotUser` that implements `IUser` while not being a `User`.
Your `User<T>()` method **could** then be called with `NotUser` as the type parameter, and that would result in a call to `GetUser()` with a type parameter that does not inherit from `User`.

Your `GetUser()` method only accept a type that inherits from `User`.

You need to either change `GetUser()` prototype to accept a generic type that implements `IUser`, or the `User<T>` prototype to accept only generic types that inherits from `User`.

Either this:

```
public T GetUser<T>(int id) where T : IUser {
    return _session.Get<T>(id);
}
```

or this:

```
public T User<T>() where T : User {
    return _usersService.GetUser<T>(1));
}
```

***EDIT:***
Whether you should pick the first or the second method depends on what you want to do.

1) You want your `IWorkContext` to work with the `IUser` interface, and you accept that the `GetUser()` method returns a `IUser` => pick option 1

2) You want the `GetUser()` method to take a type that inherits from `User`, and you accept that the `IWorkContext` interface works with `User` instead of `IUser` => pick option 2, and modify the `IWorkContext` interface.

To me, option 1) is better, as you don't need to modify the interface and you don't break the genericity. But it depends on what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I was thinking that too, but since User implements IUser, I thought that it would be able to accept it.

Comment: See my example. There could be a class that implements IUser, but doesn't inherit from User. The strongest condition is always enforced by the compiler, in order to avoid type inconsistency (I mean, if a User type is required, GetUser could use methods or fields that are specific to User, and not to IUser)

Comment: 'DefaultWorkContext' does not implement interface member 'IWorkContext.User()'. 'DefaultWorkContext.User()' cannot implement 'IWorkContext.User()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IUser'.

Comment: This is because modifying the where clause as in option 2 result in your User<T>() method in the class DefaultWorkContext not implementing the User<T> method described in the IWorkContext interface. What option you should pick, and what you should do solely depends on what you want to do with these classes/interfaces. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. After abit of refactoring I have come up with something that works for this scenario. I've hit another small snag but it's unrelated so I'll post that in another question. Thanks again.